# Setting an element's style doesn't take change immediately

Tags: javascript, css

So I've got an element with the style `pointer-events: none;` to prevent the user from clicking it, however I'd like to click it as part of my JS code, this is what I did:

```
function click(x, y) {
    element.style.pointerEvents = "auto";

    let event = new MouseEvent("mousedown");
    event.clientX = x;
    event.clientY = y;
    element.dispatchEvent(event);

    element.style.pointerEvents = "none";
}
```

However, this doesn't do anything, and it's because `element.style.pointerEvents = "auto";` does not take change immediately, so I wrapped the latter part into a `setTimeout` with a delay of `200`:

```
function click(x, y) {
    element.style.pointerEvents = "auto";

    setTimeout(function() {
        let event = new MouseEvent("mousedown");
        event.clientX = x;
        event.clientY = y;
        element.dispatchEvent(event);

        element.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    }, 200);
}
```

Apparently only `100` does not seem to be enough, is there any way to do all of this without using a hacky, ugly `setTimeout`?

Comment: It probably depends on the css engine and it might be that on some slower devices, even 200ms will not be enough. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with disabling pointer-events but wanting to manually call the event? This whole thing feels like a hack, the `setTimeout` is just a cherry on the top. Can't you just extract whatever the event does to another function and call it directly, instead of the `click(x, y)` function?

Comment: @MarkoGrešak Basically I'm doing this for an `iframe` element in order to prevent the `wheel` event from not being fired